# ImportError: cannot import name App

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to follow the tutorial on [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYNWK2GpwgA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe_l6XiJ40yGTEqIKugAdTy&index=1).

But `from kivy import App` gives `ImportError: cannot import name App`. How can I fix this?

I have installed kivy 1.8.0 and cython 0.20

`pip freeze` returns

```
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
Cython==0.20
Kivy==1.8.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.1
numpy==1.11.0
pygame===1.9.1release
requests==2.11.0
unity-lens-photos==1.0
virtualenv==15.0.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `from kivy.app import App` ([documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html)).

Comment: thanks so much Karln. I'll accept as answer when it's enabled :)